# Axis label re-centering in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am plotting specific slices of a [700,700] numpy array. I am doing `plt.plot(data_array[:,350])`, since I need to see the variation of the X values for the mid value of Y-axis. It looks like the following [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkmnP.png)

As is seen, the centre where the value of Y-axis peaks is 350. However, if I want to label the x axis in such a way that the value is 0 at the peak with -350 and +350 on either side of it, is there a way this kind of labelling can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can just subtract 350 from each value of the array. It will shift all the values to the left - starting from -350, middle point at 0 and maximum at 350.

Generally speaking, what you are looking for is standardization: you want the expectation of your array to be zero. You can use scikit-learn's [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
result_arr = StandardScaler(with_mean=True, with_std=False).fit_transform(data_array)
```

It calculates array expectation and subtract it from each value (x-E(x)). Noticc I used `with_std=False`, otherwise it will take into consideration variance of your array.

Comment: your answer was helpful for standardisation of the values. However, my particular problem was solved  by defining another array `y=np.arange(-350,350,1)` and using this as the X-axis!